# get client ip address in spring boot security

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

This is my first question here, I'm sorry if there is something wrong, please correct me).
 
I am working on a spring boot application with spring boot security. 
I use `RestController` for the creation of my API.
I need to log the IP address of all clients who try to access my API, even if they are not authenticated. 
I can get the client's IP after authentication or when the client accesses to the public API by this (get from `HttpServletRequest`):

```
    @GetMapping("/api/public/getDeviceList")
    public List<Device> getDeviceList(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        System.out.println(httpServletRequest.getRemoteHost());
    }
```

But when the client accesses a private API with wrong credentials, I don't get these IP addresses.
How can I retrieve this information?

Answer (score 4):

The method `getRemoteHost()` returns the name of the client system as a string.

The method `getRemoteAddr()` returns the client's IP address that's accessing your Java web application

Try with this on your method controller

```
System.out.println(httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr());
```

If your server is local it will return you `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` but if you test on another computer on your local network, the correct ip should be shown, for example `192.168.1.4`

Comment: Yes, sorry, i write wrong method. httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() this is correct. I mean in my question, that i can't see client's ip address, while they not authenticated.If they try to access for example ```@GetMapping("/api/private/getDeviceListPrivate")``` and set wrong login/password i can't log client's ip in this case. If they

Comment: For example, if somebody will try to find correct password for user and will check different password. I can't get this situations.

Comment: You need to use the method to obtain the IP at the moment the user enters the password, in the method where the login is

Comment: José, thank you for help. I find solution that i need in adding custom filter. I will write this below. Best regards

Comment: Hello @Bardales I tested on another computer on my local network and `request.getRemoteAddr()` is still returning : `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.

Answer (score 2):

I get solution in adding custom filter in security chain. In this filter i can log all information i need. Create filter:

```
public class CustomSecurityFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        System.out.println("Enter custom filter");
        System.out.println("method:"+request.getMethod() + "\nurl:"+request.getRequestURI()+"\nip address:"+request.getRemoteAddr());
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

then add this filter in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in configure(HttpSecurity http) method

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/private/**").authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
// -----Add new filter in chain-----
      http.addFilterBefore(new CustomSecurityFilter(), 
      SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/public/**");
    }
}
```